# Composable monadic lambda/std::function with std::optional

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm attempting to build a `Filter` type that can act as a composable error-handling callable (i.e. a Maybe monad with << implementing >>=) that (ideally) works with (at least) lambda's and `std::function` in C++17 (no need for compatibility with older standards). Ideally, something that would work like this:

```
// two example Filter's instantiated from lambda's
Filter g = [](const int a, const int b) -> float {
                  return a + b; 
           };
Filter f = [](const float c) -> std::optional<int> {
              if c < 0 return std::nullopt;
              else return c + 1;
           };

// compose them - only two right now for brevity
auto h = f << g; // so that this implements f(g(...))

// and then later call them with some arguments
h(1.0, 2.0);
```

If any of the intermediate functions return `std::nullopt`, I need the entire composition to return `std::nullopt` and for this to work over any number of composed functions (that may or may not return optionals).

The implementation that I have so far (inspired by [this post](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/07/07/optional-monad-cpp-without-ugly-stuff/)) works for `std::function` when composing two simple functions but regularly fails when combining multiple functions that change whether there return types are optional or not since the type deduction is extremely fragile.

```
#include <functional>
#include <optional>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename TReturn, typename... TArgs>
class Filter {

  public:

  /**
   * The filter function that we evaluate.
   */
  std::function<TReturn(TArgs...)> eval_;

  /**
   * Construct a filter from a std::function.
   */
  Filter(std::function<TReturn(TArgs...)> f) : eval_(f) {}

  /**
   * Apply the filter to given arguments.
   */
  auto operator()(TArgs... args) const {
    return this->eval_(args...);
  }

  /**
    * Compose this function, `f`, and `g`.
    */
  template <typename TOReturn, typename... TOArgs>
  auto operator<<(Filter<TOReturn, TOArgs...> other) const -> Filter<TReturn, std::optional<TOArgs>...> {

    // the result of the resulting function f(g(...))
    using TFReturn = std::optional<typename TReturn::value_type>;

    // the type of the resulting function f(g(...))
    using TFuncType = std::function<TFReturn(std::optional<TOArgs>...)>;

    // construct (and return) the composed function
    TFuncType f = [this, other](std::optional<TOArgs>... args) -> TFReturn {

                    // if we got a good value, perform the function composition
                    if ((args && ...)) {

                      // evaluate g over the input arguments
                      auto gresult = other(*(args)...);

                      // if we got a non-fail result from g, then call f
                      if (gresult) {

                        // and evaluate our own function over the result
                        return this->eval_(gresult);

                      }

                    } // END: if ((args && ...))

                    // if anything falls through, return failur
                    return std::nullopt;

                  };

    return f;

    } // END: operator<<


}; // END: class Filter


auto main() -> int {

  // a couple of test functions
  std::function<int(float, float)> f1 = [](const float a, const float b) -> int {
             return a * b;
           };

  std::function<std::optional<int>(int)> f2 = [](const int c) -> std::optional<int> {
               if (c < 0) return std::nullopt;
               else return c;
             };

  std::function<std::optional<int>(int)> f3 = [](const int d) -> std::optional<int> {
               if (d > 10) return 10;
               else return d;
             };

  // these construct fine if I have explicitly typed std::function's above.
  Filter f = f3;
  Filter g = f2;
  Filter h = f1;

  // build the composition
  auto F = g << h; // this works!
  // auto F = f << g << h; // this does not work

  // evaluate our composition over different arguments
  auto x = F(1.0, 2.0);
  auto y = F(-1.0, 2.0);

}
```

Composing two simple functions, `f << g`, works but `f << g << h` currently fails with the following error:

```
filter.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Filter<TReturn, std::optional<TOArgs>...> Filter<TReturn, TArgs>::operator<<(Filter<TOReturn, TOArgs ...>) const [with TOReturn = std::optional<int>; TOArgs = {int}; TReturn = std::optional<int>; TArgs = {int}]’:
filter.cpp:98:17:   required from here
filter.cpp:55:43: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::function<std::optional<int>(int)>) (std::optional<int>&)’   55 |                         return this->eval_(gresult);      |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/functional:59,                 from filter.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/std_function.h:617:5: note: candidate: ‘_Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = std::optional<int>; _ArgTypes = {int}]’  617 |     function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/std_function.h:618:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::optional<int>’ to ‘int’  618 |     operator()(_ArgTypes... __args) const      |                ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/std_function.h:601:7: error: ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = Filter<TReturn, TArgs>::operator<< <std::optional<int>, {int}>::<lambda(std::optional<int>)>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = std::optional<int>; _ArgTypes = {std::optional<int>}]’, declared using local type ‘Filter<TReturn, TArgs>::operator<< <std::optional<int>, {int}>::<lambda(std::optional<int>)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]  601 |       function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
```

How can I modify the type deduction to support `std::optional<T>(...)` and `T(...)` functions in arbitrary compositions?  Or is there a fundamentally different way to approach this solution?

Comment: `auto operator<<(Filter<TOReturn, TOArgs...> other) const -> Filter<TReturn, std::optional<TOArgs>...> {` --> is TReturn a typo?

Comment: @KorelK No - the return type of `f(g(...)` is the return type of `f` which is `TReturn`. So, `f(g(...))` is a function from `TOArgs -> TReturn`

Comment: Oh sorry, missed the types above the class.

Comment: What is it that you want `h(1.0, 2.0)` to even mean? `g` is unary but you're passing two arguments to it... and then `f` is binary and you're passing one argument to it. Is this just backwards?

Comment: @Barry. Apologies - I got the order of f and incorrect when providing the example (note: it is correct in the sample code that is provided). I've updated the question and sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand your code but... seems to me that the problem is in this section (removed comments and simplified a little)

```
auto gresult = other(*(args)...);

if (gresult)
   return this->eval_(gresult);
```

What type is `gresult`?

I suppose you expect that is a `std::optional` of some type, so you test if is valid (`if (gresult)`) and pass it to the following `eval_()`.

But what happens combining `g()` and `h()`? And combining also `f()`?

If I understand correctly, `h()` is executed before and return a `int`; so `gresult` is a `int`.

When you check

```
if (gresult)
```

you don't check if `gresult` is valid, but if `gresult` is zero or not.

But this works (I mean... compile) and the integer value is used to call `g()` that waits for a `int const`.

But when the result of `g()`

```
auto gresult = other(*(args)...);
```

(that is a `std::optional<int>`) is used to call `f()` (that waits for a `int`), you have that

```
if (gresult)
```

correctly check if `gresult` is valid, but when you call `f()`

```
   return this->eval_(gresult);
```

you pass to `f()` a `std::optional<int>()`, not a `int`.

Not sure about the solution (not sure about what you exactly want and about the `std::option` deduction guides) but seems to me that you should impose that `gresult` is a `std::option` of some type

```
std::option  gresult{ other( args.value()... ) };
```

so the following check

```
if ( gresult )
```

is ever about the validity of `gresult`, next you have to pass the **value** of `gresult` to the following function

```
return this->eval_( gresult.value() );
```

Observe that, in the following code,

```
int a;

std::optional  b{a};
std::optional  c{b};

static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(b), std::optional<int>> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(c), std::optional<int>> );
```

both `b` and `c` are `std::optional<int>`

I mean... using deduction guides for `std::optional`, if the argument is a `std::optional`, the resulting type is the same.

I suppose that this should works, for you, but I'm not sure about what you exactly want.